# How to INSERT a row into a table with two FK in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Let's say that we have 3 tables in MySQL like so:

- T1 {id_t1, id_t2, id_t3} with foreign keys {T2.id_t2, T3.id_t3}
- T2 {id_t2, foo, bar} with primary key {id_t2}
- T3 {id_t3, baz} with primary key {id_t3}

I want to insert a new row to T1, T2 and T3, where creation of a T1 row requires creation of T2 and T3 rows. I cannot do it with 3 `INSERT` queries, because the value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` changes after creation of a row.

However I need to create T2 and T3 rows right before a T1 row.

How could I create a pipeline that creates T3 and T2 rows, then with their PK creates a T1 row?

Comment: Are you doing this in raw SQL or are you using a language like php

Comment: Because T1 has two PK from T2 and T3 @CarlosGª-muñoz

Comment: An SQL will be sent to the MySQL via a driver written in NodeJS @RiggsFolly

Comment: If you are in node, surely you can capture the last_insert_id's in the javascript

Comment: But a pipeline is sent from the JS driver. Therefore latest inserted id is not known by the driver before 3 of those rows are created. @RiggsFolly

Comment: I ment FK* @CarlosGª-muñoz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture the `LAST_INSERT_ID` using variables

```
INSERT INTO T2 ... ;
SET @var2 := last_insert_id();
INSERT INTO T3 ... ;
SET @var3 := last_insert_id();

INSERT INTO T1 SET
id_t2 = @var2,
id_t3 = @var3
;
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know we could store variables directly. Thank you for the answer! This one was the pipeline I was looking for!